# Does apple allow us to take the user's mobile number upon registration?

Tags: ios, appstore-approval

I have an application where i need to take the mobile number of users upon registration, and then verify the phone number by sending a pin code to his number.
Is this against apple's policies?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about an app store's policies and procedures, rather than programming. See [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No that is not against Apple's Policies, apps such as WhatsApp do this.

However, according to Apple's [Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/interaction/authentication/) you should delay sign up as long as possible and also explain why such information is necessary for your app.